# snackbarmanaegr cant detect activity in adapter

Tags: android, snackbar

I get an error when use `snackbarmanager` in my swipe adapter like below:

> 12-23 10:53:18.298 5285-5285/com.tosa.university E/SnackbarManager: Couldn't get Activity from the Snackbar's Context. Try calling #show(Snackbar, Activity) instead
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: com.tosa.university.AppController cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
>                                                                           at com.nispok.snackbar.SnackbarManager.show(SnackbarManager.java:36)
>                                                                           at com.tosa.university.SampleAdapter.onSwipe(SampleAdapter.java:209)
>                                                                           at com.tr4android.recyclerviewslideitem.SwipeAdapter$1.onSwipeRight(SwipeAdapter.java:56)
>                                                                           at com.tr4android.recyclerviewslideitem.SwipeItem.dispatchOnSwipeRight(SwipeItem.java:325)
>                                                                           at com.tr4android.recyclerviewslideitem.SwipeItem$DragHelperCallback.onViewDragStateChanged(SwipeItem.java:389)
>                                                                           at android.support.v4.widget.ViewDragHelper.setDragState(ViewDragHelper.java:874)
>                                                                           at android.support.v4.widget.ViewDragHelper$2.run(ViewDragHelper.java:335)
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5272)
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)

Comment: post your code of snackbar

Comment: you have to pass layoutname in the place of Activity where you want snackbar to be displayed , Example      Snackbar.make(relativeLayoutParent, e.toString(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: this is my code:
SnackbarManager.show(
                        Snackbar.with(mContext).type(SnackbarType.MULTI_LINE)
                                .text(s).textColor(Color.WHITE).color(Color.parseColor("#ffc107")));

Comment: Edit your question and add your SwipeAdapter class, to finding out how to resolve your problem.

Comment: @RRR this is my code: SnackbarManager.show( Snackbar.with(mContext).type(SnackbarType.MULTI_LINE) .text(s).textColor(Color.WHITE).color(Color.parseColor("#ffc107")));

Comment: How did you get the Context for mContext variable? Did you fill it with activity context?

Comment: @MajidDaeiNejad i change the getapplicationcontext() in my activity to Myclass.this and it works like a charm
thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the error logs:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.tosa.university.AppController cannot
>   be cast to android.app.Activity

Your problem is because of using wrong Context instead of Activity Context. Change your mContext initialize to get right Activity context in your SwipeAdapter.

Comment: yes i change the getapplicationcontext() in my activity to Myclass.this and it works like a charm thank you :)